# Segmentation fault in double pointer looping

Tags: c

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="a,b,c,d,e";

  struct stri {
          int i;
          char *data;
  };
  struct stri **pstri = NULL;
  char *pch;
  pch = strtok (str,",");
  int i = 0;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf("before: %s\n", pch);
    pstri = realloc(pstri, (i + 1) * sizeof(struct stri*));
    struct stri *s = malloc(sizeof(struct stri));
    s->i = i;
    s->data = strdup(pch);
    pstri[i] = s;
    i++;
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
  }
  //update
  // should I realloc here too?
  pstri[i] = NULL;
  //update


  int j = i;
  for(i = 0; i<j; i++) {
    printf("after: %d=>%s\n", pstri[i]->i, pstri[i]->data);
  }

  struct stri *k = NULL;
  while(k = *pstri++) {
    printf("after2: %d=>%s\n", k->i, k->data);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

output is

```
before: a
before: b
before: c
before: d
before: e
after: 0=>a
after: 1=>b
after: 2=>c
after: 3=>d
after: 4=>e
after2: 0=>a
after2: 1=>b
after2: 2=>c
after2: 3=>d
after2: 4=>e
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You need to reserve extra for `NULL` pointer and set it as the last element. (Also `*pstri++` :If `pstri` is changed directly, it must be returned before `free`)

Comment: Segmentation fault can be caused by one of the following: (1) dereferencing a null pointer (when trying to do * on `(pstri+5)` after printing `after2: 4=>e` as the data at `pstri+5' can be all 0. OR (2) if the data at `pstri+5' is not 0, then data at `k=*(pstri+5)` might be zero, which will cause a seg fault due to dereferencing a null pointer when you try to do `k->i` or `k->data`. OR (3) if data at `k=*(pstri+5)` is not zero, but `k->data` might be taking the program outside allowed memory region while the program is looking for a null termination for `k->data`.

Comment: To avoid this you might want to do: set `pstri+5 to NULL` and modify to `while( (k = *pstri++) != NULL )`.

Comment: Why do you expect `pstr[5]` to be `NULL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While loop exit when `pch = strtok (NULL, ",")` makes pch NULL but we haven't set NULL at `i = 5` for pstri. This same segmentation fault can happen if you set `j = 6` instead of `j = i` because `i` is protecting this `after:` loop.